# Dell Studio Slim 540s JBOD RAID

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, raid, jbod

I'm working on a Dell Studio 540s that has dual 750GB drives in what appears to be a JBOD configuration.  The computer reports "Missing operating system" at boot.  The BIOS appeared to have been wiped/reset as the clock was set to 2007 and there were BIOS checksum errors at startup.

A linux rescue disk shows the following partition table on disk 1, and the second disk has no partition table. This is why I think it's some kind of JBOD config, as the last partition is big enough to include the second disk.

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format.
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code DE00; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
1465137457 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sdc: 1465149168 sectors, 698.6 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 963EC2D4-9A70-4968-96EC-A69C5885681A
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1465149134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 533 sectors (266.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              63          128519   62.7 MiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   2          129024        31586303   15.0 GiB    0700  Microsoft basic data
   3        31586304      2930286591   1.3 TiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
```

Since both the BIOS has a RAID option for the SATA controller, and Windows 7 has software RAID this leads me to ask:

### Is it BIOS RAID or Windows 7 software RAID?

### How can I get this system functioning again?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just setting the BIOS back to using a RAID (1) level and see if it works?

Comment: That worked. I was worried that the BIOS might modify drive contents or something and wipe it all out - Thanks!